# Getting data from JSON file in R

Tags: json, r

Lets say that I have the following json file:

```
{
  "id": "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31",
   "currentCompany": "",
   "currentTitle": "--",
   "currentPosition": ""
}
```

I use the following code:

```
Usersfile <- ('trial.json') #where trial the json above
library('rjson')
c <- file(Usersfile,'r')
l <- readLines(c,-71L)
json <- lapply(X=l,fromJSON)
```

and I have the following error:

```
Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                   {
                 (right here) ------^
```

But when I enter the json file(with notepad) and put the data in one line:

```
{"id": "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31","currentCompany": "","currentTitle": "--","currentPosition": ""}
```

The code works fine.(In reality the file is really big to do it manually for each line). Why is this happening? How can I overcome that?

Also this one doesnt work:

```
{ "id": "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31","currentCompany": "","currentTitle": "--","currentPosition": ""
}
```

**EDIT**: I used the following code that I could read only the first value:

```
library('rjson')
c <- file.path(Usersfile)
data <- fromJSON(file=c)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Surprised this was never answered! Using the jsonlite package, you can collapse your json data into one character element using `paste(x, collapse="")` removing EOF markers for proper import into an R dataframe. I, too, faced a pretty-printed json with exact error:

```
library(jsonlite)

json <- do.call(rbind, 
                lapply(paste(readLines(Usersfile, warn=FALSE),
                             collapse=""), 
                       jsonlite::fromJSON))
```

Comment: I have a one column as JSON, in a data frame. Trying to unnest json column using tidyjson::spread_all(). I get the same error EOF., Do you know how to approach it ?

Comment: @user5249203 Please ask a specific question with reproducible example. Context matters. (Once done, please remove your comment for future readers given this answer is over 5 years old).