# r How to parse pretty-printed JSON with newlines within character strings

Tags: r, json, parsing, newline, ndjson

I am struggling to parse a JSON in R which contains newlines both within character strings and between key/value pairs (and whole objects).

Here's the sort of format I mean:

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "name": "Try to parse this",
    "description": "Thought reading a JSON was easy? \r\n Try parsing a newline within a string."
}
{
    "id": 987654,
    "name": "Have another go",
    "description": "Another two line description... \r\n With 2 lines."
}
```

Say that I have this JSON saved as `example.json`. I have tried various techniques to overcome parsing problems, suggested elsewhere on SO. None of the following works:

```
library(jsonlite)

foo <- readLines("example.json")
foo <- paste(readLines("example.json"), collapse = "")

bar <- fromJSON(foo)
bar <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(foo))
bar <- purrr::map(foo, jsonlite::fromJSON)
bar <- ndjson::stream_in(textConnection(foo))
bar <- read_json(textConnection(foo), format = "jsonl")
```

I gather that this is really NDJSON format, but none of the specialised packages cope with it. Some suggest [streaming in the data with either jsonlite or ndjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519455/error-parsing-json-file-with-the-jsonlite-package) ([or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643178/export-json-from-spark-and-input-into-r) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276184/json-using-jsonlite-parsing-error-in-r)). Others suggest [mapping the function across lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858345/parse-error-trailing-garbage-while-trying-to-parse-json-column-in-data-frame) ([or similarly in base R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958344/getting-data-from-json-file-in-r)).

Everything raises one of the following errors:
`Error: parse error: trailing garbage` or `Error: parse error: premature EOF` or problems opening the text connection.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: That block (as a whole) isn't legitimate *json*, are those two dicts normally either (a) within a list, or (b) stored line-by-line, ndjson-style?

Comment: Does:`jsonlite::prettify(  )` work for you?

Comment: Hi @r2evans, no this is what I've got to work with - and I can't see a way to coerce it back into either of those formats...

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e - I've just tried `minify` as a first step but it fails in a similar manner to my other attempts to read it in...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Knowing that the json is wrongly formatted, we lose some ndjson efficiency but I think we can fix it in real time, ***assuming*** that we clearly have a close-brace (`}`) followed by nothing or some whitespace (including newlines) followed by an open-brace (`{`)

```r
fn <- "~/StackOverflow/TomWagstaff.json"
wrongjson <- paste(readLines(fn), collapse = "")
if (grepl("\\}\\s*\\{", wrongjson))
  wrongjson <- paste0("[", gsub("\\}\\s*\\{", "},{", wrongjson), "]")
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(wrongjson, simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
str(json)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id         : int 123456
#   ..$ name       : chr "Try to parse this"
#   ..$ description: chr "Thought reading a JSON was easy? \r\n Try parsing a newline within a string."
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id         : int 987654
#   ..$ name       : chr "Have another go"
#   ..$ description: chr "Another two line description... \r\n With 2 lines."
```

From here, you can continue with

```r
txtjson <- paste(sapply(json, jsonlite::toJSON, pretty = TRUE), collapse = "\n")
```

(Below is the original answer, hoping/assuming that the format was somehow legitimate.)

---

Assuming your data is actually like this:

```
{"id":123456,"name":"Try to parse this","description":"Thought reading a JSON was easy? \r\n Try parsing a newline within a string."}
{"id": 987654,"name":"Have another go","description":"Another two line description... \r\n With 2 lines."}
```

then it is as you suspect ndjson. From that you can do this:

```r
fn <- "~/StackOverflow/TomWagstaff.json"
json <- jsonlite::stream_in(file(fn), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
# opening file input connection.
#  Imported 2 records. Simplifying...
# closing file input connection.
str(json)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id         : int 123456
#   ..$ name       : chr "Try to parse this"
#   ..$ description: chr "Thought reading a JSON was easy? \r\n Try parsing a newline within a string."
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id         : int 987654
#   ..$ name       : chr "Have another go"
#   ..$ description: chr "Another two line description... \r\n With 2 lines."
```

Notice I've *not* simplified to a frame. To get your literal block on the console, do

```r
cat(sapply(json, jsonlite::toJSON, pretty = TRUE), sep = "\n")
# {
#   "id": [123456],
#   "name": ["Try to parse this"],
#   "description": ["Thought reading a JSON was easy? \r\n Try parsing a newline within a string."]
# }
# {
#   "id": [987654],
#   "name": ["Have another go"],
#   "description": ["Another two line description... \r\n With 2 lines."]
# }
```

If you want to dump it to a file in that way (though nothing in `jsonlite` or similar will be able to read it, since it is no longer legal ndjson nor legal json as a whole file), then you can

```r
txtjson <- paste(sapply(json, jsonlite::toJSON, pretty = TRUE), collapse = "\n")
```

and then save that with `writeLines` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for this @r2evans, seems like I'm stuck with a file that's just not legit JSON...